# How to save the state of the Custom Dialog?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

In my project, I have created a custom dialog inside which, I have a color palette that is initialized with a particular color(say Yellow) already checked. If I click on any color(say Blue), a tick image will come on top of the Blue color and the tick image from the previously checked color(Yellow) will be removed. Now, if I am rotating the emulator screen, the dialog is getting revert back to its initial state (with Yellow color checked). So, how can I save the state of the dialog?

Comment: hi@anshulgoel72,Could you please post some code ? Let me check the info to see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the usecase specified, you may use Preferences class in HarmonyOS (ohos.data.preferences.Preferences) to save the color integer that was recently selected by the user when there is a configuration change like rotation of the screen or device language change.

1. Use

```
preferences.putInt(key, value);
```

to store the value before the dialog is going to be destroyed.

2. Use

```
preferences.getInt(key, DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

to retrieve the value when the dialog is recreated after being destroyed due to configuration change.

For more information, please refer the [documentation](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-references/preferences-0000001054518652)